# Regex match on multiple overlapping occurrences?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that look like:

```
sometext 3x 24x5 x 17.5 x 3 sometext
```

And I would like to concatenate all instances of digit + optional space + x + optional space + digit into digit + x + digit. Desired output:

```
sometext 3x24x5x17.5x3 sometext
```

My current Regex seems fine, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
re.sub(r'(\d)\s?([x])\s?(\d)', r'\1\2\3', 'sometext 3x 24x5 x 17.5 x 3 sometext')
```

Yields

```
sometext 3x24x5 x 17.5x3 sometext
```

It seems this has to do with the fact that the 24x5 is already captured by the expression, so it doesn't consider 5 x 17. My question would be, how to adjust my regex for the desired purpose, and, is there any more clean/efficient way to write that regex than my approach? Thanks!

Comment: Please consider selecting the best answer if the solutions below work for you. Else, please provide more feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `re.sub` to identify all number-x terms, then use a callback to strip all whitespace from each match:

```
inp = "sometext 3x 24x5 x 17.5 x 3 sometext 1 x 2.3 x 4"
output = re.sub(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\s*x\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+', lambda m: re.sub(r'\s', '', m.group(0)), inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
sometext 3x24x5x17.5x3 sometext 1x2.3x4
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest two options:

```
import re
s = 'sometext 3x 24x5 x 17.5 x 3 sometext'
print (re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=x)|(?<=x)\s+(?=\d)', '', s))
print (re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?=x\s*\d)|(\d)\s*(x)\s+(?=\d)', r'\1\2', s))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2MIVvW). Both return `sometext 3x24x5x17.5x3 sometext`, but the second seems to be more precise.

**[Regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/cERPmy/2) details**

- `(?<=\d)\s+(?=x)`  - one or more whitespaces between a digit and `x`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=x)\s+(?=\d)`  - one or more whitespaces between an `x` and a digit

**[Regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/cERPmy/3) details**

- `(?<=\d)\s+(?=x\s*\d)`  - one or more whitespaces between a digit and `x` + zero or more whitespaces and a digit
- `|` - or
- `(\d)\s*(x)\s+(?=\d)`  - matches a digit (captured into Group 1), then one or more whitespaces, then `x` (captured in Group 2) and then `\s+` matches 1 or more whitespaces followed with a digit.

The replacement is the concatenation of Group 1 and 2 values.